# Como generar vista previa de mas de una foto

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileupload

Estoy usando en un script con jquery para subir en este caso imágenes presionando el boton "+", agrego hasta diez, del lado del servidor lo tengo resuelto con PHP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona todo perfecto, con su epígrafe o pie de foto para cada una.

Pero el cliente ahora me pide que se vea una imagen previa de cada una y no solo su nombre antes de subirla como hasta ahora: Seleccionar foto, ver preview y agregar pie de foto si corresponde para cualquier cantidad seleccionada y conservar la opción de borrar de la lista.

Asi debería verse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que tengo:

```
<div class="form-group galeriaMas">
                                                 
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px">
           <input type="file" name="foto_gal[]" id="foto_gal" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <input type="text" name="epi_gal[]"  id="epi_gal[]"  class="form-control  input-md" placeholder="Epigrafe">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default agMas"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group galeriaMasCopy" style="display:none;">
                                            
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px">
         <input type="file" name="foto_gal[]" id="foto_gal" />
    </div>
                
    <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
         <input type="text" name="epi_gal[]"  id="epi_gal[]" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Epigrafe">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom:5px">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
    </div> 
  </div>     

</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxGroup = 10;
    $(".agMas").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.galeriaMas').length < maxGroup){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group galeriaMas">'+$(".galeriaMasCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.galeriaMas:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
            alert('Maximo permitidos '+maxGroup+' campos.');
        }
    });
   
    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
          $(this).parents(".galeriaMas").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Lo cierto es que esta rutina de javascript no la realicé yo ni tampoco soy muy conocedor de js, más bien hago desarrollos backend, recurro a vosotros a ver si me pueden dar una mano de como resolver.

Nota: eh encontrado y probado funciones JS como la siguiente, pero que solo muestran el primer preview.

```
<input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" name="foto_gal[]" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />


 <script type="text/javascript">
  
                                                    imgInp.onchange = evt => {
                                                    const [file] = imgInp.files
                                                    if (file) {
                                                      blah.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
                                                    }
                                                  }

                                                  </script>
```

Desde yá, agradezco infinitamente a quién me pueden dar una mano.

Comment: es pq `id="imgInp"` -> `imgInp.onchange = ...` se engancha por id, los id si no son únicos toma el primero. tendrías que enganchar el evento a todos los input via una class o un `input[type=file]`  y dentro del preview usar un `this`, lo que hace es ver si hay un archivo crea un objeto de url y se lo asigna al src de una imagen ( blah ) que tambien está por id

Comment: que tiene que ver esto con php, hasta donde se php se ejecuta de lado del servidor ...

Comment: que tal ArcanisGK507..."del lado del servidor lo tengo resuelto con PHP", era para dejar en claro el panorama y el contexto.